# Validate multiple inline objects in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to validate the data that comes to my Basketball League Manager, and I got most of the easy one's but I don't know how to tackle a couple of them.

I have `Game` model and `PlayerBoxscore` model that's linked to the `Game` by `ForeginKey` (every player in that game has a `PlayerBoxscore`) and has all the stats i.e. `is_starter` and `min`.
I'm adding all `PlayerBoxscore`s while changing `Game` in Django Admin via. `inlines`, grouped by `Team`.

How can I ensure that exactly five `PlayerBoxscore`s in a `Team` has `is_starter` set to `True`?
And similar - how can I ensure that the sum of minutes in all `PlayerBoxscore`s (in a `Team`) is equal `x`.

I don't know where to put the validation; it covers all the objects linked to `Game`, so I can't put it in `PlayerBoxscore` `clean` method, or trigger it while everything is saved, because I want to prevent it from being saved when those conditions aren't met.

Thanks in advance

admin.py:

```
class AwayPlayerBoxscoresInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlayerBoxscore
    verbose_name_plural = 'Away players'
    exclude = ['team']
    readonly_fields = ['player']
    extra = 0
    max_num = 0
    can_delete = False

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Returns only players from away team
        qs = super(AwayPlayerBoxscoresInline, self).get_queryset(request)

        if request.obj is not None:
            return qs.filter(player__team=request.obj.away_team)
        else:
            return qs

class HomePlayerBoxscoresInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlayerBoxscore
    verbose_name_plural = 'Home players'
    exclude = ['team']
    readonly_fields = ['player']
    extra = 0
    max_num = 0
    can_delete = False

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Returns only players from home team
        qs = super(HomePlayerBoxscoresInline, self).get_queryset(request)

        if request.obj is not None:
            return qs.filter(player__team=request.obj.home_team)
        else:
            return qs


@admin.register(Game)
class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    view_on_site = True
    list_display = ('pk', 'away_team', 'home_team', 'score', 'winner', 'date', 'overtime')
    list_filter = ['away_team', 'home_team']
    fieldsets = [
        ('Game info', {'fields': ['away_team', 'home_team', 'date']})
    ]

    @staticmethod
    def score(obj):
        return '{away} - {home}'.format(away=obj.final_score['away_team'], home=obj.final_score['home_team'])

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        request.obj = obj
        return super(GameAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if self.get_object(request, object_id).date <= date.today():
            PeriodScoreInline.extra = 0
            self.inlines = [PeriodScoreInline, AwayPlayerBoxscoresInline, HomePlayerBoxscoresInline]
        else:
            self.inlines = []

        return super(GameAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom formset for your inlineadmin class. A clean method on that formset would be the appropriate place for this logic.